What happened to the variant rules in the new 5e?
In the past, the 5e rules contained a large number of rules variants, like the variant for creatures giving half cover, or for encumbrance, that allowed the DM to tweak the level of abstraction or detail.
However, the only mention of a Variant Rule I could find in the Index of the new edition is a variant on Equipment Sizes (p. 219, PHB), and the ToC of both published books (which contained the majority of such rules in 2014) has not yielded anything either.   I do not have a digital version to search on D&DB, so it’s difficult to check for all mentions of "variant", "optional" etc, but this seems to be quite a change from the earlier "there are many different ways to play depending on your taste, all valid" stance of 5e.
Are there no other rules variants in the entire core ruleset of 2024 5e? If there are any, where can I find them?
(For what it's worth, given there is no index entry for them, I would find it useful to have a place where they are all referenced, if they still exist).

Are you just asking for a list of all the variant rules and their locations? I’ve downvoted because this seems like a pretty straightforward “lacks research” question. If you read the books, I imagine you’d find any and all variant rules in the process. This reads like “I have the means to do the research for this question, I just want someone else to do it.”

@TreeSpawned Related meta on “list questions”: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6442/62294

@ThomasMarkov - Correct, I am asking for a list of all the variant rules, mostly because I was unable to find any, after perusing both the index, ToC, and looking at some of the places where they used to be. It's not that I have done no research, but given that I have no access to a reliable search function, it is very hard to be sure I have not missed something. Someone with a D&DB accoutn may be able to do that.

@NobodytheHobgoblin I honestly don't know anymore. I'll retract my close vote and let the rest of the community decide this.

The fact is that the new core rules are not complete yet, the MM has to be published. With just the 2 current manuals, that I understood you already have read, what is the point of this question?

@Eddymage I am just wondering if they essentially got rid of variant rules, which is quite an attitude change from the earlier „there are many ways to play“ version 5e. And I have not read the rules cover to cover yet. There may be well variants in places I missed to check.

@NobodytheHobgoblin Yes, the dev team are doing a lot of wrong things, the discarding of useful variant rules among them.

Many of the variant or optional rules from the 2014 Core Rulebooks are not present now.
The 2024 Monster Manual hasn't been released yet, so for now, these are the variant or optional rules in the 2024 PHB and DMG:

PHB:

Playing on a Grid (Chapter 1: Playing the Game, p. 25)
Variant: Equipment Sizes (Chapter 6: Equipment, p. 219)


DMG:

Miniatures (Chapter 2: Running the Game, p.44). This section expands the rules in the PHB for depicting combat with miniature figures on a grid.
Variant: Training to Gain Levels (Chapter 2: Running the Game, p. 49)
Defeated, Not Dead (Chapter 3: DM's Toolbox, p. 63). Kudos to TreeSpawned for spotting it!
Loyalty (Chapter 3: DM's Toolbox, p. 89)
Renown  (Chapter 3: DM's Toolbox, p. 92)




"Defeated, not Dead" on page 63 of the DMG is another variant rule

If the old 2014 variant rule isn't re-written or specifically contraindicated in a new 2024 rule, you can still use it.
Via Treespawned's helpful contribution, Variant Encumbrance doesn't appear (yet, at least) in 2024, but there's no reason you can't still use it, according to the Lead Designer.
Per Jeremy Crawford on backwards compatibility between 2024 and 2014,
“If something doesn't appear in the 2024 Player’s Handbook, you are welcome to pair it with a thing that does,” cited here from this article.

Is this your opinion? Your experience? Or do you have a citation from the 2024 books that supports this claim?

@ThomasMarkov Per Jeremy Crawford, “If something doesn’t appear in the 2024 Player’s Handbook, you are welcome to pair it with a thing that does,” discussing the backwards compatibility of 2024 with 2014. I'll add it to my answer along with a link to the article quoting him. The defining principle of why 2024 is still compatible with 2014 is that if there isn't a new printing replacing an old one, the old ones are still usable.

I don't dislike the content of your answer, but I think it comes off on the wrong foot. It's probably better phrased as something like "You can still use (almost) all the Variant rules of the 2014 Rules" and then explaining an example i.e. Variant Encumbrance, that doesn't appear in the new book but hasn't been replaced either.

I don’t see how that quote from JC has much to do with the claim being made in this answer.

To be clear, I’m not saying the quote is irrelevant. You just don’t explain its relevance to the answer or question. You just make a claim, then quote JC,  and without context, it isn’t clear to me what the quote has to do with the claim you’re making.

@ThomasMarkov His claim is "You can still use the old 2014 variant rules, that haven't been overridden, when playing the new version" and the quote says "If a 2014 rule doesn't appear in the new books, you can still use it as legacy content of you want, as it hasn't been overridden" meaning the quote verifies that you can indeed still use those old rules.

@TreeSpawned I suppose there’s a sense in which that supports the claim “valid”, but it falls short of supporting the claim that any variant rule from 2014 will still be functional when dropped into the 2024 rules, which seems to be the main thrust of this answer.

@ThomasMarkov I'm not sure how much more support I can provide other than the lead designer directly stating a principle of compatibility. There's no interpretation being made here, just a direct quote. Did they replace the variant rules in 2024? No. Can you use things that don't exist in 2024 with things that do? Yes.
Individual hiccups may arise if a particular new rule conflicts with an old variant, but that would fall under reprinted rules being replaced.
What standard would meet your definition of supporting the claim? I'm not opposed to meeting it but am uncertain what actually lacks.
